# Can't access website admin panel , https to http migration misconfiguration

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

Website Backend: codeigniter php 
So I was trying to change http to https to my website, My college has a SSL certificate in our college domain in which http was working fine, I added these 3 line to my main .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

So basically what is doing is redirecting to https whenever a request is made to http, Since I haven't configured my https properly, It is showing

> This page cant be reached

When I was trying change back my .htaccess file I couldnt even open admin panel because the admin panel is in the same domain , so it is again showing the error.
Anyone help me please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Besides the rewrite rule, have you configured Apache to listen on port 443 and respond to https rather (or in addition to) http?. It seems that the website is unreachable because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

try this way